# How do I ping6 a link local address on OSX?

Tags: wifi, ipv6

On linux I see all connected IPv6 addresses to my wlan adapter with

```
ping6 ff02::1%wlan0 | head
```

but how can I achieve this on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX the wifi device has another name, usually "en1", so this works on OSX:

```
ping6 ff02::1%en1 | head
```

you find out the name with

```
ifconfig
```

and look for a device that has an IP in a line precieding "inet" with an IP that is within your network

Comment: If `ifconfig` is not present on your system, use `ip a s`

Answer (score 0):

That article might be of some help: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-test-ipv6-network-with-ping6-command/

Answer (score 0):

If you read the MAN page about `ping6` then it would be:

> *The following will probe hostnames for all nodes on the network link attached to wi0 interface.  The address ff02::1 is named the link-local all-node multicast address, and the packet would reach every node on the network link.*

`ping6 -w ff02::1%wi0`

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ping6.8.html